# Com puxar uma variável fora da função PHP

Tags: php

Estou montando um código para fazer comentários porém a conexão com o banco de dados fica fora da função, sendo assim, é necessário recolocar o código dentro da função, como eu puxo o código que está fora?

```
include 'sis-config.php';
    include 'sis-checar.php';
    $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $usuario, $senha, $db);
    if (!$conn) {
    echo "Não foi possível conectar-se ao MySql." . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
    }
    function comentar()
    {
        include 'sis-config.php';
        $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $usuario, $senha, $db);
        if (!$conn) {
        echo "Não foi possível conectar-se ao MySql." . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
        }
        if (isset($_POST['comentar']))
        {
            $nome=$_POST['nome'];
            $msg=$_POST['mensagem'];
            $vrc1=checar($nome);
            $vrc2=checar($msg);
            $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $p = "INSERT INTO `chat` (`nome`, `ip`, `mensagem`, `vip`) VALUES ('$vrc1', '$ip', '$vrc2', '0');";
            if ($conn->query($p) === TRUE) {
                echo 'Postado com sucesso';
            } else {
             echo "Erro: " . $p . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }

        }
    }
```

Quando eu removo o

```
include 'sis-config.php';
    $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $usuario, $senha, $db);
    if (!$conn) {
    echo "Não foi possível conectar-se ao MySql." . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
```

da função, a query não funciona, quero que funcione sem ter que recolocar o código dentro da função

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passe por parâmetro:

```php
function comentar($conn) {
  ...
}
```

E quando for chamar a função, faça `comentar($conn)`. É para isso que existem os parâmetros da função, gerenciar os escopos.

Comment: Muito obrigao consegu

Comment: @VictorStanford Recomendo que leia também sobre o princípio de responsabilidade única, pois te ajudará a escrever funções mais consistentes.